# Mac OS X 10.8 not binding to Windows domain

Tags: windows, macos, active-directory

I have five iMacs with OSX 10.8.5. Two of the iMacs are binding to Windows domain server (2012) successfully. But I can’t bind remaining three iMac machines, and it is showing authentication error `5202`, `5200` error and some times it shows `2000` error. It is able to access windows share using domain user ID.

There is no issue when binding any Windows OS version (XP/7/8) to the domain.

I have checked the following things:

- Verify the time of iMacs with Windows server
- DNS resolution

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 10.0.8 or 10.8?  Hopefully the latter.  Here's where I'd start

1. Try running `dsconfigad -show` and make sure that the computer account matches what you see in ADU&C on your Windows Server.  If your Mac had spaces in the name (e.g., My Cool Mac), your AD server might not be interpreting it correctly.  Also make sure your advanced Administrative options are not in conflict
2. I've experienced issues on Macs when the 3 different computer names are out of sync.  Run `scutil` and make sure that *HostName*, *ComputerName* and *LocalHostName* are all in sync.  You can use the --set option to modify them.
3. Make sure that the accounts joining to the domain have enough rights to join to the OU you've specified and that the user's AD group has access to login to the mac from the network.  You can do this from the Directory Utility.

HTH

Comment: I can't add imac machines to windows domain.The dsconfigad -show,for Mac that was already added to domain.

Comment: In my experiences, joining OSX to AD is not as forgiving as joining a Windows box (go figure).  Try using the **-force** option of `dsconfigad` to remove it from the domain.  Then try adding it back to AD without the **-force** option.  If that fails, try again _WITH_ force.  One of these should work.  GL.

Answer (score 0):

We had this error:

> dsconfigad: Authentication server encountered an error while attempting the requested operation. (5202)

and in the `/var/log/opendirectoryd.log`

```
...
2016-03-10 11:08:30.210484 GMT - AID: 0x0000000000000000 - 1280.6968, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5.dylib - krb5_get_init_creds: KRB-ERROR -1765328378/Client (XXXX@YYYY.COM) unknown
2016-03-10 11:08:30.210505 GMT - AID: 0x0000000000000000 - 1280.6968, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - password verify for XXXX@YYYY.COM failed with error -1765328378 - 'Client (XXXX@YYYY.COM) unknown'
2016-03-10 11:08:30.210574 GMT - AID: 0x0000000000000000 - 1280.6968, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - ODNodeCustomCall failed with error 'Credential server error' (5202)
...
```

joining a machine running 10.11.x that had been unbound from the domain.  Nothing would allow it to bind - using either OpenDirectory or `dsconfigad`

The fix was deleting the following:

```
/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/config/
/etc/krb5.keytab
/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory
```

This issue affected two machines which have now been able to successfully bind.

Comment: beware: we followed these steps and the machine will no longer boot.